# Como filtrar resultado de outra pagina com Jquery Load() ou Get()?

Tags: html, jquery, get, load

Em um HTML tenho por exemplo:

```
<fieldset>
    <div>
        <h3 class="title title-line">Dados da conta</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="ch-form-row">
        <label>Usuário</label>
        <span>MEU-USUARIO</span>

        <a class="smalla" href="https://myaccount.mercadolivre.com.br/profile/changeNickName">Modificar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="ch-form-row">
        <label>E-mail</label>
        <span>xyz@gmail.com</span>
        <a class="smalla" href="https://myaccount.mercadolivre.com.br/profile/changeEmail">Modificar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="ch-form-row">
        <label>Senha</label>
        <span>**********</span>
        <a class="smalla" href="https://accountrecovery.mercadolivre.com.br/accountrecovery/changePassword">Modificar</a>
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Preciso de Outra página capturar o Nome de usuário e salvar numa variável, o mais próximo que conseguir alcançar com `jQuery Load()` foi:

```
$( "#id-de-teste" ).load("https://myaccount.mercadolivre.com.br/profile .ch-form-row span:first", function(data, status){
username = $('#retorno_webtracker').html();
alert(username);
    });
```

Porém eu tive 2 problemas: A variável com o Username ficou também com as tags `<span>`, e eu não quero/preciso que este valor seja exibido na página, só preciso dele na variável para prosseguir com a rotina do script.

Com `jQuery Get()` consigo "baixar" a página com os dados que preciso, no entanto não estou conseguindo filtrar somente a classe .ch-form-row depois a primeira tag

```
$.get("https://myaccount.mercadolivre.com.br/profile", function(data, status){
        //alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
//username = $('span',$('.ch-form-row')).html();
filtro = data.getElementsByClassName('ch-form-row');
console.log( filtro );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Consegui resolver

```
$.get("https://myaccount.mercadolivre.com.br/profile", function(data, status){
        var username = $('.ch-form-row span', $(data)).html();
//todo o codigo que precisa da variavel
});
```